# ReadError: file could not be opened successfully. But I am not sure where the tar file is stored to resolve this

Tags: bert-language-model, word-embedding, sentence-transformers

I am using `biobert-embeddings==0.1.2` and `torch==1.2.0` versions to embed some documents. But, I get the following error when I try to load the model by

`from biobert_embedding.embedding import BiobertEmbedding`

`biobert = BiobertEmbedding()`

Output/Error I get is -

> Extracting biobert model tar.gz

> ReadError: file could not be opened successfully

Comment: I am getting the same. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the same issue. Please follow the below steps to run the model:

1. Download the model from the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvsemunmv0htmdk/biobert_v1.1_pubmed_pytorch_model.tar.gz?dl=0
2. Extract all the files from the downloaded tar.gz file.
3. Use code:

`biobert = BiobertEmbedding(model_path = "location_you_installed")`

Note: Please make sure "location_you_installed" has config.json, pytorch_model.bin, and vocab.text files. These files are obtained after step 2.